# No DHCPOFFERs received. No working leases in persistent database - sleeping. (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, dhcp

First of all, I would like to clarify that I have very little knowledge about operating systems and computing in general, which unfortunately prevents me from using technical terms. For my (biology) internship I had to install Ubuntu on a empty server. I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 using a bootable USB made with Rufus (created by following the tutorial from Ubuntu). After installation, Ubuntu couldn't connect to the ethernet and find the IPv4 or IPv6 adresses which were shown during booting. After booting, I got the following output while running `dhclient`:
`No DHCPOFFERS received. No working leases in persistent database - sleeping`
While trying to find a solution to the problem, I also got the following by running `ip -a`:
`eno1:<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> ...`.

I tried rebooting as well as running `dhclient -v -r` followed by `dhclient -v` but this didn't change anything. I also tried a different cable in order to fix the NO-CARRIER, but this also didn't work.

Running `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` gives the following output:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Comment: Is this in a corporate or academic environment? you may need to ask your network administrator(s) to whitelist the interface's MAC address to allow it on the network

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Please redact any sensitive information with xxxx. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: does your LAN use DHCP? systemd/networkd doesn't use dhclient (I think).

Comment: @steeldriver It is a corporate environment. There is only one person who has any IT knowledge and manages everything at the company. I will ask them to check if this is indeed the case. Thank you!

Comment: @chili555 I added it to the question. Thank you!

Comment: @DougSmythies I am not sure, I will look into it. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Suggest you decide on one interface only, at least for now. Also specify a renderer. I'll write an answer to demonstrate, but might delete it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was fixed by using another cable and port in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Save your current `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file. Then edit it, using `sudo`, specifying only one nic, at least to start:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Comment: And follow with: `sudo netplan generate` and then: `sudo netplan apply`

Comment: Thank both of you for the help, the problem was luckily unexpectedly fixed after I (again) tried another cable and another port in the server.